# Can a coroutine in C# return a string value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am using Unity and C# to build a game that when a player hovers a mouse over an item, a UnityWebRequest is called to process a SPARQL query. I would like to return a string for the JSON response that is output by the query.  I am having trouble gettng a returned value from the coroutine. So far I have tried using a "callback", though I am not completely sure how this works. After the coroutine retrieves the data from the webrequest, I would like to manupulate the JSOn response. Does anyone knwo how to get this to work or have any tips? Thank you!!

#### SCRIPT THAT CALLS COROUTINE

```
internal class HighlightSelectionResponse : MonoBehaviour, ISelectionResponse
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI gameText;
    public RESTGet rest;
    private static string itemName;
    private string URL;
    string returnData;

    public void OnSelect(Transform selection)
    {
        // this method only works if a query toggle is checked
        if (rest.queryUsage == true)
        {
            var itemName = selection.name.ToString();  // name of the gameobject
            var URL = rest.queryURL + itemName;
            Debug.Log(URL);

            // START COROUTINE
            StartCoroutine(rest.GetData2(URL, (value)=> { returnData = value; } ));
            Debug.Log(returnData);  <=== returns Null
        }
    }
```

#### SCRIPT WITH COROUTINE

```
public IEnumerator GetData2(string uri, System.Action<string> callback)
{
        UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri);
        // Call/Request website and wait to finish
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
        if (webRequest.isNetworkError || webRequest.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log("No response from website");
        }
        else
        {
            //process web result             
            Debug.Log("Data retrieved!");
            callback(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is that you are trying to use the returnData before it has been returned. The coroutine is an asynchronous function that will terminate at some point in the future, so you must perform any actions on the returned value *only after it has completed*. This is usually done by continuing the code flow within the callback. For example:

```
            // START COROUTINE
            StartCoroutine(rest.GetData2(URL, (value) => {
                // This function is called after GetData2 has completed.
                returnData = value;
                Debug.Log(returnData); // <=== logs value
            } ));
            // This code flow continues IMMEDIATELY AFTER we START COROUTINE,
            // and has not waited for GetData2 to complete, so it logs null
            Debug.Log(returnData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Russopotomus answer is better, but the way i do it is like this:

First i create the function or object that will process the data (in my example ObjectCtrl is receiving a JSON Object), then i invoke the CoRoutine and pass the data as a parameter

Hope it helps somebody

```cs
public class ObjectCtrl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Label
    {
        get { return _details.Find("Name").GetComponent<Text>().text; }
        set
        {
            _details.Find("Name").GetComponent<Text>().text = value;
        }
    }

    public void SetData(JSONNode product)
    {
        Id = product["id"];
        Label = product["name"];

        // Add more fields here....
    }

}


public class ObjectCtrl : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetProductInfo(url));
    }

    public void SetData(JSONNode product)
    {
        Id = product["id"];
        Label = product["name"];

        // Add more fields here....
    }

    protected IEnumerator GetProductInfo(string uri)
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri);
        // Call/Request website and wait to finish
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogError(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            //Process web result             
            Debug.Log("Data retrieved!");
            JSONNode product = JSON.Parse(www.downloadHandler.text);

            // If the data is needed by a member I only need to call the member:
            SetData(product);

            // If the data is needed by another object i search for the object
            ObjectCtrl objCtrl = objContainer.GetComponent<ObjectCtrl>();
            objCtrl.SetData(product);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And then never invoke the `callback`? ;)

Comment: sorry... edited

Comment: this made it worse ;) .. there is no `ObjectCtrl` in OP's code .. the question is rather why is the `Debug.Log` after `StartCoroutine` not displaying the correct value ... you should stick to the `Action<string>` but have to invoke it and actually start the coroutine with passing in the according callback as parameter

Comment: edited again, I hope it makes it more clear like this

Answer (score -3):

Try to use a `ref` key word and pass `returnData` by reference:

```
public void OnSelect(Transform selection)
    {
        // this method only works if a query toggle is checked
        if (rest.queryUsage == true)
        {
            var itemName = selection.name.ToString();  // name of the gameobject
            var URL = rest.queryURL + itemName;
            Debug.Log(URL);

            // START COROUTINE
            StartCoroutine(rest.GetData2(URL, ref returnData));
            Debug.Log(returnData); 
        }
    }
```

```
public IEnumerator GetData2(string uri, ref string returnValue)
{
        returnValue = "";
        UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri);
        // Call/Request website and wait to finish
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
        if (webRequest.isNetworkError || webRequest.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log("No response from website");
        }
        else
        {
            //process web result             
            Debug.Log("Data retrieved!");
            returnValue = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response! Unfortunately, I get the error that iterators cannot have ref parameters.